# How to load .eps file to canvas

Tags: reactjs, fabricjs

I have a function which get eps file from download url.
It returns blob file. I tried both `fabric.loadSVGFromString` and `fabric.loadSVGFromURL` but none work.

Does fabricjs support loading eps file?

Answer (score 0):

An EPS is an Encapsulated Post Script file, quite different from an SVG file.  You would need a conversion from EPS to SVG, there are quite a few out there, you may look at ImageMagick.